# OCaml Tree Operation

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am trying to write methods on arbitrary trees in OCaml. Here is my tree constructor:

```
type 'a tree =
  | Leaf of 'a
  | Node of ('a tree) list
```

I am having trouble with `fold_tree`:

```
let rec fold_tree (f : 'b list -> 'b) (g : 'a -> 'b) (t : 'a tree): 'b.
For example, fold_tree sum (fun x -> x) (node [node [leaf 7; leaf 8]; leaf 9])=24
```

Comment: It looks like an assignment to me, if you want an answer please consider adding more details on what you tried. Stack overflow is not a place to find people that will do your homeworks

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish here... Is it something like this?

```
let rec fold_tree f acc (t:'a tree) =
  match t with
  | Leaf e -> f acc e
  | Node l ->
    List.fold_left
      (
        fun a e -> fold_tree f a e
      ) acc l
```

Example of usage:

```
let data = Node [Node [Leaf 7; Leaf 8; Leaf 100]; Leaf 9; Leaf 10;]

let ans = fold_tree (fun a e -> a + e) 0 data

let () = print_endline(string_of_int ans)
```